# I have a question about ways to shorten the code and using certain range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have not enough knowledge about apps script so I used the macro and tried to shorten codes but couldn't find the way to shorten this code.
Also, I'm wondering if there's a way to select the certain ranges and autofill for only that range.

Currently, I have no idea, so I just put the whole column...;;
And got an exception pop-up says "Exception: Cell reference out of range ('macro' file, line 30)"
the last code line of the below codes is the line 30
(spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F3001').activate().sort({column: 1, ascending: true});)

Could you help me out solving this problem? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
function myFunction3() { var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A2:B2').activate();
var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();

spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet9'), true);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'sheet8\'!A2:B').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('A2:A').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(),
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false); 

var dupl = spreadsheet.getRange('E2:E').activate();
dupl.removeDuplicates();

spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A:A', 'E:E']).activate().setNumberFormat('@');

spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=if(E2="","",date(year(E2),month(E2),day(E2)))');
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('d2:d3001'), 
SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=iferror(TEXTJOIN("\n",true,QUERY($A$2:$B,"select B where A =\'"&E2&"\'")),"")');
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F2:F3001'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F3001').activate().sort({column: 1, ascending: true});};
```

Comment: Quit using activate. Quit using ranges like ‘A2:A’.

Comment: If you rewrite the question making the recommendations I suggested you may get a better response because it will look more like something that we would write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The column number you specify in [sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) refers to the whole spreadsheet, not to the range

In other words, column `1` is column `A` - even if your range starts with `E`.

If you want to sort your range by column `E`, modify your request to

```
spreadsheet.getRange('E2:F3001').sort({column: 5, ascending: true})
```